# Onclick Listener is not working in Device?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

IN my application i had a textview and i  added the onclick listener to it, it works fine o my emulator.but not working in my device. can anyone suggest wht its happen soo? this is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/call_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Call"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_txt_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call"
        android:background="@drawable/route_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Route"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_txt_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/route"
        android:background="@drawable/email_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_txt_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/web_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Web"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_txt_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this my code

```
route = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.route);
route.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(AnotherDetail.this,
                    MapRouteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Not getting any error click is not working? but wrks on emulator

Comment: Show your logs from `Logcat`.

Comment: `TextView`s need to be focused to report click events. Did you try tapping it twice?

Comment: Wait, I got confused. I thought it was an EditText. My bad. Carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz,  try increse the textview size, because some time we click in textview but actually it's click on relative layout not on text view,so try to increse your textview size or set oncllick listener on relative layout